# Checking if condition on Long type for velocity template

Tags: velocity

Long type from java is not working with velocity if condition

I am using velocity engine for email with Java where one of the variables type is Long.
While trying if condition on that variable it never succeeds.

Tried following ways but none was helpful,

```
#if($customTypeList.LongTypeId == 1)

#if($customTypeList.LongTypeId == '1')

#if($customTypeList.LongTypeId == "1")
```

It should go inside the if condition as variables value is 1.
I have validated that with sysout and even by printing in template.

Comment: I wonder which version of Velocity you are using. With 1.7, all three tests do work.

Comment: Are you trying with type long or Long? Version is 1.7

Comment: All values in Velocity are Objects, not integral types, if needed they are boxed. You can check this by displaying `$customTypeList.LongTypeId.class.name` (provided you're not working under a SecureIntrospector). There must be some other weird cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually got the answer after number of trials...
Posting to help others.

```
#if($customTypeList.longTypeId.intValue() == 1)
```